# Prove an expression is a constant integer

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Define $$a_n=w-2nv,b_n=u\sqrt{n},e_n=\sqrt{a_n^2+b_n^2},c_n=a_n/e_n,d_n=b_n/e_n$$
and
$$X_n=\frac{(e_n^2+e_{n+1}^2) \left(c_n \left(u^2+4 v^2\right)+4 \sqrt{n} u v d_n-4 (2 n+1) v^2-u^2\right)
+2 e_{n+1} e_n \left(c_{n+1} \left(c_n \left(u^2-4 (2 n+1) v^2\right)+4 \sqrt{n} u v d_n-u^2+4 v^2\right)+4 \sqrt{n+1} v d_{n+1} \left(u \left(c_n-1\right)+2 \sqrt{n} v d_n\right)\right)}{\left(e_n^2-e_{n+1}^2\right){}^2}$$
$$Y_n=\frac{(e_{n-1}^2+e_n^2) \left(c_n \left(u^2-4 v^2\right)+4 \sqrt{n} u v d_n+4 (2 n-1) v^2+u^2\right)
-2 e_n e_{n-1} \left(c_{n-1} \left(c_n \left(u^2-4 (2 n-1) v^2\right)+4 \sqrt{n} u v d_n+u^2+4 v^2\right)+4 \sqrt{n-1} v d_{n-1} \left(u (c_n+1)+2 \sqrt{n} v d_n\right)\right)}{\left(e_{n-1}^2-e_n^2\right){}^2}$$
(In $X$ and $Y$, the two upper parts are together the nominator. It's due to display width if they are separated.)

All variables are real.
I numerically find that $X_n+Y_n=2$ always holds for any integer $n$. This is expected as it is related to some quantization in physics. But how to prove this mathematically?

Comment: A monster expression ! Multiply it out and look which terms cancel out or can be combined.

Comment: You have expressions like $e_{n-1}, e_n, e_{n+1}.$ Is there a recurrence relation involved?

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII No recurrence relation involved as far as I know.

Comment: When you start comparing the definitions of $a_n$ thru $e_n$ with their uses in $X_n, Y_n$, you start seeing what looks like considerable obfuscation. In fact, it almost seems deliberate, though I could see it possibly occuring from failing to simply an ongoing calculation. For example, note from examining the definitions of $d_n, b_n, e_n$, that in fact, there is no taking of square roots of $n$ or $n-1$ needed to calculate $X_n$ or $Y_n$. The only potential need for square rooting at all is in evaluatiing $e_{n-1}e_n$ in $X_n$ and its shift in $Y_n$.